# Removing a comma from an array

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that removes comma from an array and features the following output:

```
sub hi.txt

sub hello.txt

sub hey.txt

sub yo.txt

sub whatsup.txt
```

My code is:

```
int main(void)
{
    int aux=0;
    int aux2=0;
    char sub[100];
    char f [] = "hi.txt,hello.txt,hey.txt,yo.txt,whatsup.txt";
    size_t n = (int)sizeof(f) / sizeof(f[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n ;i++)
    {
        if(f[i] == '.')
        {
            for(int c=aux; c<i+4;c++)
            {
                sub[aux2] = f[aux];
                aux++;
                aux2++;
            }
            aux=i+5;
            aux2=0;
            printf("sub %s\n",sub);
            sub[0]='\0';
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However the result that is coming is:

```
sub hi.txt

sub hello.txt

sub hey.txtxt

sub yo.txttxt

sub whatsup.txt
```

Comment: Have a look at [`strchr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

Comment: You're not terminating the strings. You have: `[h,e,l,l,o,.,t,x,t,\0]`, then set it to `[\0,e,l,l,o,.,t,x,t,\0]` and in the next iteration you write `hey.txt` without null-terminator over it, so you get `[h,e,y,.,t,x,t,x,t,\0]`. In other words, you read the garbage left by the previous word, and only if you're lucky to get a 0 at some point in the uninitialized `sub` array.

Comment: Also, it's a weird choice to use the extension as separator when you already have the commas (and null terminator for the last word). I think it'll end up much nicer, if you give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You're not null terminating your substring.  Add
`sub[aux2] = '\0';` before you set `aux2 = 0`

As an aside, you'll find it easier to get the string length using the `string.h` function `strlen`

`size_t n = strlen(f);`

Answer (score 1):

While manually looping is fine (you may find using a *start* and *end* pointer easier than indexing), C already provides functions that can tokenize a string on a set of delimiters (`strtok`, and `strsep`). In your case you can use `strtok` to trivially separate your string contained in `f` into individual substrings, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char f[] = "hi.txt,hello.txt,hey.txt,yo.txt,whatsup.txt";

    /* tokenize f on , */
    for (char *p = strtok (f, ","); p; p = strtok (NULL, ","))
        printf ("sub %s\n\n", p);
}
```

(**note:** `strtok` modifies the original string by inserting `'\0'` in place of the delimiters, so you will need to make a copy if you need to preserve your original string.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitoncomma
sub hi.txt

sub hello.txt

sub hey.txt

sub yo.txt

sub whatsup.txt
```

The additional functions that are provided that can be used are `strcspn` and `strspn` (can be used in conjunction without modification of the original string), or for single-character delimiters as you have, `strchr` or a pair of pointers can be used as well.